# mysql backup without mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I'm having this issues where I cant do a mysqldump (server restarts, errors, etc)

Anyone have tried doing an rsync or copying the raw data on a live server without stopping the mysql server?

Comment: do u have the right privileges to do that?? errors??

Comment: yes i have all the privileges. i just cant use the mysqldump on this machine since it hangs any one used rsync?

Comment: IMHO, if `mysqldump`'ing the database crashes MySQL, there is a serious issue. You should bring the database down and fix it ASAP. And make a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

Go for MySQL Enterprise Backups